# Calculate the arclength of $y=\frac{\sqrt{x}(x^2+2)}{3}, \hspace{0.5cm} 2\leq x\leq 4$

Tags: definite-integrals

Calculate the arclength of 
 $$y=\frac{\sqrt{x}(x^2+2)}{3}, \hspace{0.5cm} 2\leq x\leq 4$$

My work: I have calculated

$$1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2=\frac{25x^4+20x^2+36x+4}{36x}$$

I need your help to solve the integral

$$\int_2^4\sqrt{\frac{25x^4+20x^2+36x+4}{36x}}dx$$

Please help me to find its EXACT VALUE.

Comment: You'll probably need elliptic integrals in order to represent the value exactly. Are you familiar with techniques for evaluating elliptic integrals?

Comment: @DavidH Sorry I don't know

Comment: Well, then I think you're going to have a very hard time finding the value. What's the context of the problem? Do you specifically need an *exact* value?

Comment: @DavidH I have to find the arc length.It is an old exam problem so I cannot use any software.I have to find its exact value.